# How to get pointer to child from method returning pointer to parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, getter-setter, getter

#### Context

The context is composed by three classes:

- abstract parent (e.g. **Player**)
- child (e.g. **TapePlayer**)
- a holder (e.g. **MyMachine**)

The holder has a member variable that is a `shared_ptr<...>` to the parent class and a setter for it accepts `shared_ptr<...>`s of children classes.

My getter looks something like this

```
shared_ptr<Parent>  getChildPtr() {
    return parentPtr;
  };
```

but it returns a pointer to the parent, and cannot access child methods. 
If I want to do something like the following

```
holder.getChildPtr()->childMethod(); 
// ERROR! No member named 'childMethod' in 'Parent'
```

**How should I implement the getter to get the pointer to the child instead of the parent class?**

#### Code

The whole code looks something like this:

```
class Player {
public:
  Player(){};
  virtual ~Player{};

  virtual void play() = 0;
}

class TapePlayer : public Player {
public:
  TapePlayer(){};
  virtual ~TapePlayer{};

  void play() { ... };
  void rewind() { ... };
}

class MyMachine {
public:
  MyMachine(); //
  ~MyMachine();

  void setPlayer(shared_ptr<Player> p) {
    playerPtr = p;
  }

  shared_ptr<Player>  getPlayer() {
    return playerPtr;
  };

private:
  shared_ptr<Player>  playerPtr;
}


MyMachine machine; // the holder

shared_ptr<TapePlayer> tapePtr(new TapePlayer()); // pointer to child

machine.setPlayer(tapePtr); // set holder with pointer to child

machine.getPlayer()->rewind(); // -- ERROR! No member named 'rewind' in 'Player'
// if I want to get the player of that machine to rewind I need
// to dynamic_cast<TapePlayer>() ...
```

**I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing this than casting to children types.  Any ideas?**

#### EDIT

This was a very simplified example.  What I'm actually trying to do is this:

> My holder class is named Clip.  A clip plays something, be it an
>   image, a video, a sequence of images, some kind of processing with
>   OpenCv, a vector shape...  anything that can be displayed.

All these types of things are Players. 
I don't care what type of player the  clip holds.  I just want it to show it to me.  But, some players need tweaking at runtime, like the OpenCv one, that needs tweaking parameters for optimal processing.  I cannot implement all methods of all subclasses in the parent class, that would make no sense to me. Why does a video need to have the methods for tweaking OpenCv parameters? 
All I need is that both have 'playable' methods, and be able to store them in a `map<string, PlayerPtr>` to access them at any time or change the player the clip is holding.

Comment: You can add a virtual rewind method to your parent class (just declaration).

Answer (score 2):

The point is that this kind of ruins the polymorphism - even with `dynamic_cast`, you still need to check that the result is not 0 (i.e. check the actual type) and as you might already know, `dynamic_cast` is famous for being very slow (and requiring RTTI information built in the executable).

Is there any reason you couldn't add a pure virtual `rewind()` method to your `Player` interface? Then you'd just call it and the inherited class could do whatever it decides in that case. Other subclasses might implement it as empty (or it can be even empty by default in the `Player` itself, so that the subclasses do not have to implement it if they don't need to). Perhaps even some more "generic" virtual function like `reset()`, `restart()` etc. which would just call `rewind()` for the `TapePlayer` under the hood.

You can of course go even more fancy with more complex solutions like visitor/observer (`TapePlayer` being `RewindObserver` and observing a `rewind` event) etc.

EDIT:

So to address the edit comments - if the different types need tweaking, then again, you can just have a single virtual method `tweak()` (pure or with default empty impl) and do whatever tweaking is needed. Otherwise you'd anyway end up with a long list of `if`s and call tweak methods depending on the actual type.

If the tweaking requires some special parameters, then the situation can be difficult ... one option could be to have a tweaking parameters interface (and call the tweak method with that), but if the params can't be unified you'd need a dynamic cast in the tweak method anyway to cast to the correct params type (this basically leads to double dispatch which in C++ requires casting at some point) ... but anyway that would still require to create different param classes in the calling site which is not that nice.

It also depends when you actually need to setup the tweaking parameters - if it is enough to setup everything when creating the instance (and the tweaking params do not change afterwards), or if it is needed to change them later on. If only needed to setup at startup, then you can have factory classes for the different object types and the factory can setup the params.

(technically you could handle even the necessity of changing the params a similar way, by keeping the setting object types for various player types, the players would keep reference to them as well, assigned when the objects are created, and once they need to be changed, you'd change the settings and call `tweak()` or `update()` or similar func to inform the objects that some setting changed and needs to be re-applied)

Comment: Do you really need a dynamic_cast for this? Even a C-style (or C++ style) static cast will do (I understand that no type checking is enforced). I do agree that this  ruins the polymorhism, well to a cetrain extent.

Comment: But for static cast you need to know in advance which type it is. If it is let's say `Mp3Player` not inherited from `TapePlayer`, then static casting it to `TapePlayer` will be undefined behavior (the casted instance might not even have the `rewind()` method), and the program will likely crash. That's why the dynamic_cast is needed, because if the type cannot be cast, it will return null pointer so it can be checked.

Comment: If Mp3Player isn't a sublass of TapePlayer, then static_cast won't compile (C++ style). Even when using a dynamic_cast, you still need to specify a type (e.g dynamic_cast<TapePlayer*>(basePtr). Am I missing something here?

Comment: I used this as a very simplified example.  The actual classes that inherit from player are very different from one another.  I'll edit to clarify what I'm trying to do

Comment: @dsp_user The point is that the `static_cast<TapePlayer *>(playerPtr)` will not know that it is casting from `Mp3Player`, because the `playerPtr` will be typed `Player *` (or shared_ptr to it which is similar case). Then `static_cast` will compile because it is allowed to cast from `Player *` to `TapePlayer *` and cannot know that it is actually an instance of type having the same base, but otherwise unrelated. For dynamic_cast you still need to specify the type indeed, but it does runtime check of the actual type and if the type is of a different inherited class, it will return 0 (or throw).

Comment: I understand  all that. I guess my point is that in the simple example the OP gave us, there's really no need for a *dynamic_cast*. Since there's no reflection in c++ we have to know the types we're using in advance. But, I agree that a *dynamic_cast* provides additional run-time type safety.